# Seam to Weld CDI

Tags: jboss-weld, jboss-seam

I would like to know how if there is a equivalent to the following seam 2.2 annotation

```
@Interceptor(around = {SomeInterceptor.class})
```

with Weld annotation.
I'm not very familiar with either Seam nor Weld.  What exactly means "around" ?  Does it have to do with orders other interceptors are called ?  Or is it some kind of inheritance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/ch07s11.html

"Where interceptor order is important, add @Interceptor annotations to your interceptor classes to specify a particular order of interceptors."

```
 @Interceptor(around={BijectionInterceptor.class, 
                  ValidationInterceptor.class, 
                  ConversationInterceptor.class}) 
 public class LoggedInInterceptor { 
... 
}
```

So with one interceptor it is not very useful ...